# Why "Modern Latin Math" font messes my plot?

Tags: plotting, ticks, fonts, matex

I just download the Modern Latin Math font from [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/lm-math/download) to have a consistent font with my LaTeX text. The font is exactly what I am looking for. But when I use it for my plot it messes the gap between the axis and the tickmarks and also between the tickmarks and the frame label.

This is the command that I use

```
ListLinePlot[stressD1, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1100, 1100}, {-1100, 1100}}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", FontSize -> 22}, 
 ImageSize -> 465, 
 FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, 
      Magnification -> 2] &) /@ {"\\sigma^\\text{t}_{1}", 
    "\\sigma^\\text{t}_{2}"}]
```

and this is what I get

[image]

However, if I use any other fonts, e.g. the MS Serif font, the plot is totally fine, see below

```
ListLinePlot[stressD1, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1100, 1100}, {-1100, 1100}}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "MS Serif", FontSize -> 22}, 
 ImageSize -> 465, 
 FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, 
      Magnification -> 2] &) /@ {"\\sigma^\\text{t}_{1}", 
    "\\sigma^\\text{t}_{2}"}]
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: What is your OS and Mathematica version?

Comment: @Szabolcs Window 10 mathematica 11.3

Comment: I don't know why, but here are some things I would try: 1. [Try this version of the fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) 2. Try the "Roman" version (not "Math"). 3. As I remember, on Windows the correct name to refer to the font was "LM Roman 12" and not "Latin Modern Roman" or "Latin Modern Math", but I can't test this on Windows right now.  Will any of these help? I have no idea. Just try them.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for your response. I used the font "LM Roman 9", which is practically the same as "Latin Modern Math", and didn't have that issue.

Comment: Good to hear!  The number in the font name is the size it is optimized for. "LM Roman 9" can be used at any size, not just 9 points, but other variants are more readable at smaller sizes. At larger sizes "LM Roman 12" would look more beautiful. In practice, it doesn't matter which one you use unless you use really tiny sizes.

Comment: If you found a practical solution, please do post a self-answer! If MaTeX users ask me about this, I can then point them here.

Comment: @Szabolcs Done!

Answer (score 4):

Following the comment of @Szabolcs, I downloaded the full package of Latin Modern Roman fonts [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) and tried them one by one to check which is the most similar to "Latin Roman Math". So I found "LM Roman 9"  to be the best option for the size of the text that I am interested in.